# "We met the students whom you taught English." Versus "We met the students whom you taught English to."

Tags: prepositions, pronouns, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, indirect-objects

I am taking classes to improve my English. The instructor and I were going through 'Relative Clauses' this morning, when this particular sentence came up.

*We met the students who  you taught English.*

The instructor said that it was wrong to use '*Who*'. He said that '*Whom*' was the correct choice in standard English. The reason he gave was that '*Who*' was subjective case and  '*Whom*' was objective case.
I got this part but I saw another error in the sentence and said that a preposition '*To*' must be added at the end of the sentence.

*We met the students whom you taught English to.*

The teacher said that it was not needed and was superflous because '*Whom*' covered for the objective case.

But I think that I may be right.
Please help me with this doubt.

Comment: James Thurber told the story of a man who was shown his wife's body in the morgue and said "It's her". The newspaper editor corrected the grammar to "it is she". If the man had actually said "it is she", the police might have wondered why he was so composed: had he already known that his wife was on the slab because he'd killed her?

Comment: @SimonCrase I read somewhere that 'It is I' goes to the extremity of pedantic behaviour. But, here in India, even prestigious tests that one takes to become a top dog in the government,  consider sentences like  'It is her'  and 'It is me' wrong.

Comment: English is a _family_ of dialects. Sometimes it is possible to find out which _part_ of a city a speaker comes from by listening. Someone who grew up in the Bronx has a different accent from Queens, even though both are from New York. One function of English is to distinguish in group and out group. Indian English is a family of dialects: my Bengali friends speak English differently from South Indian friends. Presumably the exams are based on a "top dog" dialect.
BTW, I would never say "is is me", as "it's me" sounds more natural (in my dialect).

Comment: @SimonCrase I am from deserts of Rajasthan in India. Nice to know that you have some Indian friends. Have you come here sometime? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I've worked with Indian software developers, and have visited India several times, mostly in the South, but my last trip was to Rajasthan: Jaipur, Udaipur, Bikaner, Mt, Abu, Jodhpur, and Ranthambore, where we saw tigers. I enjoy visiting India. The people are lovely, and there is always a lot of energy.

Comment: You can say "to whom you taught English". Ending clauses with prepositions is common but, in this case, avoidable.

Comment: @JohnDouma Is it a case of preference or involves the dichotomy of formal and informal English? When should I prefer the prepositional ending? If you could clarify a bit more...

Comment: I avoid using a preposition at the end of a sentence whenever possible. Winston Churchill once quipped "that is non-sense up with which I shall not put". To his point, sometimes it is awkward to follow that rule. For example, "where do you come from?" sounds better to me than "from where do you come?".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the “who/whom” distinction has just about disappeared in spoken American English except among very careful users. (I do not know about British English.)

Second, let’s start with direct and indirect objects. For verbs that can take a direct and indirect object, there are two equally grammatical ways to go.

> I taught English to him

or

> I taught him English

If the indirect object follows the verb and precedes the direct object, there is no preposition preceding the indirect object. If the direct object follows the verb and precedes the indirect object, the indirect object is preceded by “to” or “for.”

Third, in modern English, the objective case is used for direct and indirect objects of verbs and for objects of prepositions. If, as I do, you retain the “who/whom” distinction, “who” is used only for a clause’s subject, and “whom” is used for all three objective uses. All three of the formations below are grammatically correct, and I give them in my personal order of preference. My most preferred is

> to whom I taught English.

I like that because it immediately makes clear that “whom” is the indirect object. Of the following, I prefer

> whom I taught English to.

I find that acceptable because the final “to” eventually makes clear that “whom” is an indirect object, but there is a delay that makes my thought somewhat hard to grasp immediately.

> whom I taught English

is correct, but I do not like it because the listener or reader is given the least information on how to parse “whom.”

These are subtle points on which good users of English may disagree.

Comment: It's similar in British English: the use of 'who' as object is commonplace, and 'whom' can sound overly correct.

Comment: I'm with Jeff that both versions are idiomatic; the final **to** is optional. It makes no difference to the meaning.  As  your teacher said, it is not required. My preference is to omit it but, as Jeff makes clear, this is a matter of taste. Other verbs would require the preposition. **....whom I spoke/talked to, conversed/argued with**.

Comment: @Jeff Correct me if you find an error in my reasoning. 'Whom' is a pronoun which refers to 'Students' in the sentence. Because the noun 'Students' would have  taken  a 'to'  because it is an indirect object. Like, "You taught English to the Students." So "Whom" must also take the preposition "to". But the place of preposition confuses me, Is "To whom" more correct than "Whom you taught English to." and Why?

Comment: @Ashutosh Yes, “whom” does refer to “students,” which is indeed an indirect object. No, there are two correct ways to indicate an indirect object (as I explain in my answer), and one of those does not require “to.” With a relative clause, the normal word order is impossible. You can omit “to” or retain it and put it before the indirect object or retain it  and put it after the direct object. All three are grammatical.

Comment: @Jeff So, My sentence which puts 'To' at last is perfectly grammatical or not? I won't offend a grammar snob, will I?

Comment: @Ashutosh Yes, it is grammatical. There **are** some who claim that ending a clause with a preposition is a grammatical error, but they are a minority. English grammar is basically Germanic and has separable verbs. So do as you like. I gave my reason for preferring placing “to” before “whom,” but it is a personal stylistic preference, not grammatical.

Comment: @Jeff Thank you very much. My understanding is now crystal-clear. I have upvoted and right-checked your answer.

Comment: @Ashutosh You’re welcome, and thank you for the upvote. I spend considerable time on my answers, and it is gratifying to learn when they are helpful.

Comment: While this isn't an answer I feel that I personally would say "We met the students **which** you taught english to." Whether this is 'correct' is not something that I can say, but I thought I would add it as no one else seems to have mentioned it. (For reference I am a British English native speaker.)

Comment: @Fishbane - as I remember learning, "which" should not refer to people, only things.  For reference, I am an American English native speaker.

Comment: I’d propose yet another alternative (also BrE): “We met the students you taught English to”. The relative pronoun feels unnecessary to me, but in this case the “to” is required.

Comment: Propositions at the end is not something I am generally snobby about, but in this example the to at the end sounds unnatural. The argument that English is basically Germanic really is neither here nor there in settling questions of grammaticality.

Comment: More natural in my eyes: "We met the students _ that _ you taught English to."

Comment: @MikeBrockington These are questions of style over and over. It is true that using “that” instead of “who” or “whom” reduces the number of options with respect to “to” to two rather than three, and you certainly may feel that “that” is more euphonious than using “to whom.” It seems to me a reasonable aesthetic judgment, but some prefer to use “who” or “whom” to refer to human beings, another reasonable judgment.